# By how much does that math trick increase chances in a lottery?

Tags: probability

There is a lottery (for example $5$ unique numbers out of pool of $36$ numbers ranging $[1,2,\ldots,36]$). Chances to win at $1$ attempt are $1/\operatorname{comb}(36,5) = 1/376992$. Chances to win at $100$ attempts: $100/376992$. So far it is clear.

But... we know for $100\%$ sure mathematically some facts: for example, say, that

1. in $43\%$ of all $376992$ combinations arithmetic mean of $5$ numbers can be just $10$ variants (in remaining $57\%$ combinations there are $50$ variants of average).
2. in $35\%$ of all $376992$ combinations there is some other observed peculiarity
3. in $30\%$ of all $376992$ combinations there is some third observed peculiarity

Now I play $100$ times and stake only on numbers satisfying all those peculiarities.

1. Do I have better chances to win?
2. How can I calculate my increased chances now? What formula to use and where to plug my $43\%, 30\%, 35\%$ into that formula?

On the one side, staking on such special numbers I have higher chances to hit into the *group of combinations **having** this special quality*, but *this is offset by the need to hit **exactly*** **one** combination **out of these many in the group.** On the other side, very small probability to hit a smaller group of numbers not possessing  such special qualities is positively compensated by the fact that is I hit that small group then there are only a few combinations in it to hit final win.

I cannot apply mathematics and formulas of conditional/unconditional probability to prove with pure math beyond any doubt. This is why I am asking. What is the probability calculation and what are reasons for selecting specific formula?

I can't agree with just quantitative reasoning without applyinbg strict calculation. And deciding to apply the right formula is hard to understand (for me) - as it is often in combinatorics...

Comment: No, this does not improve your chances of winning. Suppose you carefully choose 5 numbers satisfying these criteria. On the other hand, I choose arbitrarily and by coincidence land on the same 5 numbers. You already know that I have only a 1/376992 chance of winning. Do you somehow have a better chance of winning than me because of all the thought you put in?

Comment: The wording seems a little unclear here.  If you are considering a win occurs only when all five numbers are correctly chosen, then there is no "math trick" involved.  However there are schemes called "lottery wheels" that improve ones chances of "winning" where it is meant that a prize can be won by correctly guessing some prescribed size subset of the five numbers drawn.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a slight variation of [The Gambler's Fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy).

For the $100$ attempts, do you mean $100$ different tickets for the same draw?  If so then your chances of winning are $100/376992$.  However, if you mean $100$ single attempts at different draws then your chances of winning are slightly less than $100/376992$.  On the other hand, you might win more than once.

If the draw is truly random then no clever strategy is going to improve your chances.  Rahul's point is good here.

In the real world, consider that even if you achieved a slight increase in your chances, it is unlikely to be enough to make a profit probable.  In many real word lotteries at most $1/2$ of the ticket income is returned as prizes.  This tells you immediately that the *expected* return is $1/2$ or less.  So, you would need to achieve a very large increase in your chances to obtain an expected profit.  Do you think that a strategy that more than doubled your chances would have gone unnoticed?

One strategy that has some value is to avoid popular entries. E.g. use the higher numbers which are less likely to be someone's birthday or other lucky number.  Avoid simple patterns on the entry form.  Best of all, generate your entry randomly.  This strategy does not make you any more likely to win but does make it less likely that you will need to share your prize if you do.  In particular, avoid 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.  I read once that this is surprisingly popular.  I guess that it is a failed attempt to to be clever: "Ha ha, many people would assume that 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 is very unlikely and won't use it but I am clever and I know that it is just as likely as any other result.  So, I will use it and I won't have to share if I win."  The trouble, too many people have thought of that. This is more psychology than mathematics.

My strategy to maximise my returns?  Simple - don't buy a ticket.