# Is Gianella Geometry templates (lotteries) + all people staking 11111 vs more probable combinations - fake?

Tags: probability

It looks obvious that there would be a difference in 2 cases:

1. All people on earth stake just at 11111 at every lottery.
2. People stake on different numbers. Try to stake on evens+odds, avoiding all evens, etc...

In the second case somebody (not necesarrily me) would win more often. Isn't it? So **this is the first question - I feel it makes difference, but I cannot explain why. Or no difference?**

I worked for a large lottery company and their employed mathematicians said that there are methods to (very modestly) increase chances to win. Yes, those methods is no threat for lotteries and won't ever beat lottery companies, but mathematicians say that if all people on earth use those methods, lottery company (huge) gains would go down (just a bit, not drastically much)... Also by their statistics (lottery companies statistics) rate of wins (very slightly) increased in recent years!!!  I'd quote their saying "Win rates recently approached theoretical maximum" - but it means only one thing - that in the past people made less probable stakes? And rate win was "below theoretical maximum"!!! What does it mean???

Please, don't tell me lottery isn't worth playing - I know it and I never played a single game! I am just interested in the math - what is truth and what is fake and huge misunderstanding. Also, please, don't tell me that chances are too small, because I am not going to stake on that chances - *even if it makes one difference in a million, I am interested to learn - why is it so?*

So what do you also think of the said above and of this method:

1) [original paper](http://jaguar.fcav.unesp.br/RME/fasciculos/v31/v31_n4/A7_RGiarelli.pdf) of brazilian mathematician

2) [Web-site](http://www.lotorainbow.com.br/en/help_metodo.asp) of this mathematician

3) Phys.org review article  [link](https://phys.org/news/2014-03-millionaire.html), same was published in Nature and well-respected journals... + my inside from lottery company...

This question is very different (being about Gianella Geometry of chance patterns), but related in a way to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2758656/by-how-much-does-that-math-trick-increase-chances-in-a-lottery). Please comment if you have a clear understanding how to apply knowledge from the practical point of view.

Comment: Mathematics can calculate the winning chances, but there is no way to calculate how to play a lottery "smart", unless you know which combinations have been bet rarely, in which case you get more money IF you win.

Comment: I had recently created a website using real-life lottery data to create patterns and grouping.  I didn't even know about his theory until today.  I also majored in math.  But incredible as it is, real-life statistical patterns MATCHED his theory patterns!  Real-life data all fall into the patterns as he has explained.  This is actually quite incredible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to improve your odds at winning a genuine lottery -- full stop.  Either the mathematicians that you worked with were mistaken, or you misheard them, or something else like that. But that claim is incorrect. Only in very special circumstances can you massage your odds, such as Blackjack where the deck isn't shuffled in between successive games. No reasonable lottery is run in such a way, and every draw is independent. (EDIT: Peter had a useful clarification in the comments; you cannot improve your chance of winning, but it's possible to improve the payout if you do win. This is still not detrimental  to the lottery because their total payout is the same.)

The paper you linked appears to commit a fairly serious error in logic. I'll try to illustrate it with the following analogy: let's say I am running a lottery in which I draw one of the 26 letters in the English alphabet from a hat. You note that there are 5 vowels and 21 consonants (counting Y here), so you point out that it is much more likely that you will draw a consonant than a vowel. You then conclude that if you choose a consonant, you are more likely to win.

Have you spotted the error in the logic? Everything was great until the very last sentence. If you actually place a bet, you still have to pick one consonant, and your one consonant is no more likely than any one vowel to be the one chosen. You don't get some sort of benefit by way of your letter being in a large group.

As best as I can tell, that's the error that's happening in the paper. The author categorizes various lottery draws into types, points out (correctly, I think) that some types are more likely than others, and draws the inappropriate conclusion that you should gravitate toward those more frequent types. It doesn't matter if you do this or not; it will not improve your odds. The paper is perhaps a modestly interesting combinatorial argument of some sort -- I'll confess I didn't read it carefully -- but it is most certainly not useful gambling advice.

I don't intend to be mean, but this paper should absolutely not have been published in that state with those incorrect claims.

Comment: Also, since I did not explicitly address your question of betting on all 1's vs. some patterned behaviors: patterns, or lack thereof, are completely irrelevant. As I mentioned in my original answer, such things cannot influence your odds of winning one way or the other.